# Accepting a partial string for an enumaerated type c++

Tags: c++, string, partial, enumerated-types

I have enumerated values for genres of music like: "Rock" "Country" "Techno" etc. We have take an input from a test script and assign it to an enumerated type. I have been able to assign the exact strings to the enumerated type for example if "Rock" was entered it would assign that object to the enumerated type of Rock; however, if Alternative Rock were entered I can not find a way to accept that partial string of Rock and assign it to enumerated type "Rock" with the genre name of "Alternative Rock" I tried using std::find but had no luck. I apologize if this questions is confusing I can elaborate more with code if needed.

Comment: Try `std::string::find()`?

Comment: @Mine so if my string is genreType, I would just do std::string::find("Rock") and that would work?

Comment: [So you tried `string::find` and it did not work?](https://ideone.com/X0NNSt) How so?

Comment: @JosephMehltretter No... just check the example of gha.st

Comment: @gha.st I had a similar code where I was doing str.find("Rock") and that was not working; however now that I created a string "Rock" it seems to working! Thanks!